# Django development Server does not reload in docker container

Tags: django, docker, cookiecutter-django

with cookiecutter-django I use the docker setup in the sync version. Unfortunately, the development server does not restart automatically on any code change. Which means I would need to restart the containers on every change, which is a hassle.

I am working with Windows 10 and Docker Desktop and the WSL 2 engine.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you use a plain Python virtual environment, without Docker?

Comment: Of course I can, but I would like to use the Docker setup of cokiecutter-django

Comment: Which OS & architecture are you using on your host machine? We had this on Mac M1: https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django/issues/3770 but it should be solved

Comment: What do you mean by 'sync version'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie-cutter django uses `runserver_plus` inside the local docker container, so more broadly the question is "How to get auto-reloading to work for `runserver_plus` inside docker on WSL2."

`runserver_plus` is built on Werkzeug, and exposes Werkzeug's built-in reloading capabilities. While Werkzeug does support filesystem event-based reloading, this doesn't work inside WSL2 when you're mounting a file path from the host.

The CLI documentation [includes a section on this specific issue](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html#io-calls-and-cpu-usage), which links to [Werkzeug's auto-reloader docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/serving/#reloader). These state that you'll need the `stat` reloader, which is a brute-force update checker that stat's all files every few seconds to look for changes. You can enable this explicitly:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus  --reloader-interval 1 --reloader-type stat ...
```

(Note that 1-second intervals might be too frequent, decrease to whatever makes sense for you.)

In Cookie-cutter Django specifically, you'll find this command in the `compose/local/django/start` script. Modify the `runserver_plus` command, rebuild the image, and restart your container.

---

The original question didn't ask about Celery, but I'll note that cookiecutter uses `watchfiles` to auto-reload celery workers. This suffers from the same issue in docker+WSL2, and can be forced to using file stat polling by setting `WATCHFILES_FORCE_POLLING=true` (in `.envs/.local/.django` in cookiecutter).